# Why is my dataOfType: not called when saving?

Tags: macos, cocoa, save, nsdocument

I have an `NSDocument` that contains a `dataOfType` method, but it is not called when I do a save.

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName 
                 error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError
{
    NSLog(@"db: %@", db);
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:db];
}
```

Why is this not called? Specifically, are there any reasons why my current document should not be the first responder that the menu-item "Save" points to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you leave 'Use Core Data' checkbox unchecked on create new project window?

Comment: I will look at that. This was a part of an experiment and I may just have selected cd!

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.