# dataOfType not called in lion document based application

Tags: cocoa, document-based

Almost same to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311101/why-is-my-dataoftype-not-called-when-saving).

I'm creating a new document based application for OS X Lion.

[This document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/ManagingLifecycle/ManagingLifecycle.html) says, I must override `dataOfType:error:` and `readFromData:ofType:error:` in a subclass of NSDocument to read / write files, so I added these methods in my document class but they were never called when I selected Open or Save menu items.

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
    NSLog(@"Read from data");
    return NO;
}
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    NSLog(@"data of type");
    return [NSData data];
}
```

I also tried to override `writeToFile:ofType:` and `readFromFile:ofType` but they also never got called.
These methods were called when I created document based applications in Snow Leopard.

Why these methods are not get called?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved.
It seems that 'Use Core Data' option was checked.